# How do I evenly space these links within my navbar div?

Tags: css

I would like to evenly space the 3 links ('About', 'Hours', 'Contact') within the containing 'banLinks' div. I do not want to use a list of any kind.

I would like each link to be evenly spaced, taking up 1/3 of their container. I am very new to HTML and CSS and I'm not sure how to do this.

I think one way of doing it may be by dividing the width of the div container in pixels by 3, account for the font size, then set the margins somehow around this figure. But to me this seems a bit unseemly, I'n not sure if this is the done thing.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">



<div class="bruceBanner">
<a href="#">
  <img border="0" alt="XYZ Banner" src="http://bit.ly/1QSpdbq" width="553"     height="172">
  </a>
 </div>

<nav>
<div class="banLinks">
 <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
 <a id="hours" href="#">Hours</a>
 <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
</div> </nav>


 </div><!-- .wrapper-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {

} 

.bruceBanner img {
border: 2px solid black;

height: 172px;
width: 553px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;  
}

.banLinks {
border: 2px solid black;
width: 553px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}


#about, #hours, #contact  {
font-size: 20px;
border: 2px solid blue;

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yuy84gmq/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using flexbox. Do as followed:

```
.banLinks {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 553px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; //or space-between whatever you like best


}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuy84gmq/10/
flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I think you missed the part *"I would like each link to be evenly spaced, **taking up 1/3 of their container**"*...anyway, I've already provided a flexbox solution.

Comment: Yea it's not the only flexbox solution :), I added your feedback to the j-fiddle they are now all 33% of their container, note that this is kind of a hack and ugly coding with almost the same as any of our flexbox solutions. https://jsfiddle.net/yuy84gmq/12/

Answer (score 0):

Add this to style:

```
.banLinks {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 553px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.banLinks a{
  width: calc(33% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a display table

```
.banLinks {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 553px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;

} 
.banLinks a {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuy84gmq/8/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options here...both of which work regardless of the number of list items...assuming there is enough width.

**Display:Table-cell**

```css
.banLinks {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 553px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.banLinks a {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<div class="banLinks">
  <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
  <a id="hours" href="#">Hours</a>
  <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
.banLinks {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 553px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.banLinks a {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<div class="banLinks">
  <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
  <a id="hours" href="#">Hours</a>
  <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of usual `a` links, put them into a list, and set the list to be inline. Then you can apply margin to the list items to space them out.

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul class="banLinks">
 <li><a id="about" href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a id="hours" href="#">Hours</a></li>
 <li><a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.banLinks li { display:inline-block;margin:0 10px;} /* Adjust left/right margin as appropriate */
```